# Deep Link Capabilities with External Applications through Banno

Tags: hyperlink, banno-digital-toolkit

We have started embedding external applications in Banno such as Atomic.  When the user clicks on the external link **within** the Banno environment, the behavior is correct.  However, we want to use the link outside of the Banno environment.  For instance, if we wanted to send a link for Atomic via email to certain users, we want the user to be able to click the link, authenticate into Banno, pass immediately to Atomic, complete their request in Atomic, and then once completed, pass the user back into the Banno dashboard.  How can we accomplish this task?

We did try to use the redirect URI in this capacity and it almost worked.  It did the first several steps, but once the user finished within Atomic, it did not pass them back to Banno.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on the scenario, so please bear with me. It _sounds_ like the link you're describing should first start by directing to _Atomic_. If the user isn't logged into Atomic, then Atomic can figure that out and do the auth redirect with Banno (which would redirect back to Atomic to complete the login to Atomic). The Atomic app could then offer the user a way back into Banno via a button (or similar). The key part would be that the Atomic app would need to ingest some sort of parameter (e.g. a query parameter on the initial link to Atomic) so they could maintain state for redirects.

Comment: The folks at Atomic would have to build in that capability, though. It's not something directly supported by the Digital Toolkit out-of-the-box.

Comment: BTW, you can simulate some of what I'm talking about by cloning + configuring the https://github.com/Banno/simple-plugin-example to run on your local machine. (Assume you would need to do the same configurations as described in the "Build Your First Plugin" quickstart.) If you visit the expected Redirect URI http://localhost:8080/dynamic directly in your browser (i.e. without viewing the plugin in Banno's Dashboard), then you'll see that you are prompted to login (if not already logged in) and then redirected back to the Simple Plugin Example's /dynamic page.

Comment: My chain of comments above is based on whether or not I've correctly understood your scenario, of course. Apologies if I've gone down the wrong path based on misinterpreting the scenario.